# Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, typeerror

Ok I have completely changed my code now so that the customers lists are inside another list. Now I am trying to refer to the individual lists for each customer with a for loop. But when I am trying to access individual values in the customer lists I am getting a TypeError: list indicies must be integers or slices, not list. Here is the code:

```
customers = [ ]
customers.append(["Bilbo","Baggins","Dodge Dart", "120876","March 20 2017"])
customers.append(["Samwise"," Gamgee","Ford Tarus","190645","January 10 2017"])
customers.append(["Fredegar","Bolger","Nissan Altima", "80076","April 17 2017"])
customers.append(["Grima"," Wormtounge","Pontiac G6", "134657", "November 24 2016"])
customers.append(["Peregrin"," Took","Ford Focus", "143567", "February 7 2017"])
customers.append(["Meriadoc","Brandybuck","Ford Focus", "143567", "February 19 2017"])



print("At Holden's Oil Change we use our custom built Python program to keep \
track of customer records \
and to display our company logo!!")
time.sleep(7)

print("Select and option from the menu!")

QUIT = '4'

COMMANDS = ('1','2','3','4')

MENU = """1   Current Customers
2   New Customers
3   Company Logo
4   Quit"""

def main():
    while True:
        print(MENU)
        command = realCommand()
        commandChoice(command)
        if command == QUIT:
            print("Program Ended")
            break

def realCommand():
    while True:
        command = input("Select an option: ")
        if not command in COMMANDS:
            print("That is not an option!")
        else:
            return command

def commandChoice(command):
    if command == '1':
        oldCust()
    elif command == '2':
        newCust()
    elif command == '3':
        Turt()

def oldCust():
    print("%6s%12s%20s%24s%22s" % ("First Name", "Last Name", "Car Make & Model", "Mileage Last Service", "Date Last Oil Change"))
    for i in customers:
        print("%8s%18s%22s%24s%32s" % (customers[i][0],customers[i][1],customers[i][2],customers[i][3],customers[i][4]))
```

the function oldCust() is where the error comes up when the for loop runs it is giving the type error. I've tried it several different ways but each ways sends back the same error.
Here is the whole error that gets returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hdaug\Documents\Holden's Personal\Spring 2016-2017\CSCI 1121\HoldensOilChange.py", line 264, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\hdaug\Documents\Holden's Personal\Spring 2016-2017\CSCI 1121\HoldensOilChange.py", line 49, in main
    commandChoice(command)
  File "C:\Users\hdaug\Documents\Holden's Personal\Spring 2016-2017\CSCI 1121\HoldensOilChange.py", line 66, in commandChoice
    oldCust()
  File "C:\Users\hdaug\Documents\Holden's Personal\Spring 2016-2017\CSCI 1121\HoldensOilChange.py", line 79, in oldCust
    print("%8s%18s%22s%24s%32s" % (customers[i][0],customers[i][1],customers[i][2],customers[i][3],customers[i][4]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code down to where we actually need to look?

Comment: I don't think you really want to put each customer in its own variable; you'll find putting them in a list much better.

Comment: Ok I got rid of all the newCust() function code

Comment: that is what I'm meaning Scott. I just want to put the inputs in something so that the user can enter multiple new customers and I can in the end print out the whole list of new and old

Comment: Answers below do not address the question as stated in the title, do they? My impression is this post isn't very useful for anyone other than the person asking - against SE good practices.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `list` to store customer variables. Then you can easily add new customer in the list.

Here is the complete solution of your problem:

```
"""
Program that is used to store service
records for prior customers or prompt
user for customer information for new customers.

The program also uses Turtle Graphics to display
the company logo.
"""
#Import time module for delays in program
import time

#Define current customers

customer_list = []
customer_list.append(["Bilbo","Baggins","Dodge Dart", "120876","March 20 2017"])
customer_list.append(["Samwise"," Gamgee","Ford Tarus","190645","January 10 2017"])
customer_list.append(["Fredegar","Bolger","Nissan Altima", "80076","April 17 2017"])
customer_list.append(["Grima"," Wormtounge","Pontiac G6", "134657", "November 24 2016"])
customer_list.append(["Peregrin"," Took","Ford Focus", "143567", "February 7 2017"])
customer_list.append(["Meriadoc","Brandybuck","Ford Focus", "143567", "February 19 2017"])


#Announce the company and what our program does
print("At Holden's Oil Change we use our custom built Python program to keep \
track of customer records \
and to display our company logo!!")
time.sleep(7)

#Tell the user what to do
print("Select and option from the menu!")

#Make the menu and menu options for the user
QUIT = '4'

COMMANDS = ('1','2','3','4')

MENU = """1   Current Customers
2   New Customers
3   Company Logo
4   Quit"""

#Define how the menu works if quit option selected
def main():
    while True:
        print(MENU)
        command = realCommand()
        commandChoice(command)
        if command == QUIT:
            print("Program Ended")
            break

#Define what happens if a invalid command is entered or a correct command is entered
def realCommand():
    while True:
        command = input("Select an option: ")
        if not command in COMMANDS:
            print("That is not an option!")
        else:
            return command

#Command selection and running
def commandChoice(command):
    if command == '1':
        oldCust()
    elif command == '2':
        newCust()
    elif command == '3':
        Turt()

#Runs old customer selection
def oldCust():
    #Print list of customers for the user to select from.
    print("%6s%12s%20s%24s%22s" % ("First Name", "Last Name", "Car Make & Model", "Mileage Last Service", "Date Last Oil Change"))
    for customer in customer_list:
        for value in customer:
            print(value,end="\t")
        print("")

#Request response from user and define what happens depending on the input.
    response = input("Ener a customers last name from the list: ")
    customer_search_result = 0
    for customer in customer_list:
        if response.lower() == customer[1].lower():
            user_milage = input("Enter current vehicle mileage: ")
            user_date = input("Enter todays date (Month Day Year Format): ")
            print("%6s%12s%20s%24s%22s" % ("First Name", "Last Name", "Car Make & Model", "Mileage Last Service", "Date Last Oil Change"))
            print("%9s%13s%19s%25.9s%34s" % (customer[0], customer[1], customer[2], customer[3], customer[4]))
            print("Have a great day!")
            customer_search_result=1

    if customer_search_result==0:
        print("That is not a current customer!")
        time.sleep(2)
        #Request user input wheter they want to input new customer info or try another customer name.
        nonCustResponse = input("Choose 1 to re-enter customer name or 2 to enter new customer info: ")
        #if statement that decides what to do with the user input
        if nonCustResponse == "1":
            oldCust()
        elif nonCustResponse == '2':
            #Send the user to the newCust function if they enter a non-current customer
            newCust()
            #If the customer enters an invalid option the program restarts
        else:
            print("That is not an option. Program restarting")
            time.sleep(3)


#Prompts user for information for the new customer
def newCust():
    #Make an empty list for the new customer to be assigned to
    new_customer = [" "," "," "," "," "]
    #Request user input for the new customer information
    new_customer[0] = input("Enter the customers firsts name: ")
    new_customer[1] = input("Enter the customers last name: ")
    new_customer[2] = input("Enter the customers vehilce (Make Model): ")
    new_customer[3] = input("Enter the vehicle mileage: ")
    new_customer[4] = input("Enter today's date (Month Day Year): ")
    print("%6s%12s%20s%24s%22s" % ("First Name", "Last Name", "Car Make & Model", "Mileage Last Service", "Date Last Oil Change"))
    print("%8s%13s%22s%25s%34s" % (new_customer[0], new_customer[1], new_customer[2], new_customer[3], new_customer[4]))
    customer_list.append(new_customer)
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I have updated some part of your original code to make it run able. This code can be improvised.

Comment: When I do all this to the code it will not link my menu item to the command choice the user inputs

Comment: I have called the main method in ```__name__```. So, you may take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow some escape code when you have finished your input, i.e. just empty string:

```
customers = []
new_customer = input('> ')
while new_customer:
    customers.append(new_customer)
    new_customer = input('> ')
```

So when the user has hit enter without writing anything, the input is done. If you want to change that 'exit code' to something more sophisticated, use this:

```
customers = []
exit_code = 'stop'
new_customer = input('> ')
while new_customer != exit_code:
    customers.append(new_customer)
    new_customer = input('> ')
```

Answer (score 0):

To save an input to multiple vars, do something like this:

```
tmp = raw_input(">>> ")
var1 = tmp
var2 = tmp
var3 = tmp
```

To use an input multiple times, use a function:

```
def function(num):
    i = 0
    while i < num:
    tmp = raw_input(">>> ")

function(3)
var1 = tmp
var2 = tmp
var3 = tmp
```